# Is it possible to have a romance with all your possibilities in one game?

Tags: mass-effect-2

Is it possible to romance all your options in a single game?

For example if you are playing as a male, that would be Tali, Jack, Miranda, Kelly, Samara.  I'm not including Morinth in this list, as if I recall, Morinth is a dead end (literally).

Has anyone ever done this?

Comment: Do note that you cannot actually have a romance with Samara. She is forbidden from that by her Justicar vows. (Though she *will* tell a Paragon Shepherd that she wishes it were otherwise)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Yes**, with one **major caveat**: You can *only* "consummate" a single romantic interest before the Suicide Mission, though you can dead-end yourself (I.e., prevent further romance) with all of the characters before this.

To observe all romantic interactions within a single playthrough, simply play the game, as normal, until you complete the suicide mission. You can romance one of the available options during this part, but limit your social interactions to *only* this character (so you don't accidentally lock yourself out of the other relationships prematurely).

**After you've beaten the main game, you can go back and start romancing the other love interests.** (You may have to do missions / visit planets in between to progress along the dialog trees) Eventually, the new character will refuse to go any further until you break up with your current love interest. If you do so, you should be able to jump directly into the romance scene the next time you speak with them (this is the scene that normally plays just before the Suicide Mission). Add another notch on Sheperd's bedpost, and continue on with the third potential romance.

Do note, you can only be romantically involved with a single character at a time, but you *can* see all possible romance outcomes in a single playthrough (of a single gender, of course. Fem Shepperd will never be able to romance Tali or Miranda, for instance).

The Mass Effect Wiki has more information on [Romance](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Romance) in general.

Comment: This is the right answer, it never occurred to me that you could delay the relationships without causing issues. +1

Comment: @Raven If I save stuff for later, will I actually have to complete missoins to get new dialogue for pursuing relationships, or would it be enough just to visit a planet, then reboard the Normandy? I'm asking because I want to know if I'd be locked out post-Omega 4 relay if I'd done all sidequests already.

Answer (score 3):

No.  You will eventually be forced to pick between them.  While you can flirt/pursue up to a certain point to actually have a relationship (and the achievement) you must make a choice.

[Romance Guide](http://faqs.ign.com/articles/107/1073018p1.html)

In addition, when you make that choice the other one becomes quite upset.