# How can I maximize romantic encounters?

Tags: mass-effect-series

So there are a lot of [good questions about romancing](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/198977/how-can-i-possibly-sleep-with-everybody?lq=1) in these games, and the [Romance Guide on the Wiki](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Romance) is awesome. A lot of it assumes that things stay pretty monogamous though, even if it is a [serial sort of monogamy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monogamy#Serial_monogamy).

But what if you wanted to be a completely Playboy Shep? That is, having as many sexual encounters as possible with as many people as possible?

**What exact steps would one have to take to accomplish this?**

This question is different from the first linked question, in that although it was asking if it was possible to do so, and the answer broke down *all* of the romance options, it didn't deal with the specific strategy to go through to do so. The answer in that other question mostly just broke down all the info from the Romance Guide.

Since I'm a straight male, I'm more interested in a straight male shep breakdown, but providing other breakdowns (straight/bi/gay male/female, although I suppose bi for either gender would be the *most* player status) would definitely improve the answer.

Comment: Hello! It seems some people don't like this question. I'd love your feedback about why :)

Comment: Actually, I'd be interested to know why this question was downvoted. Maybe ask on http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com

Comment: Is it allowed for people to downvote purely based on not liking the tone/content of the question?

Comment: + 1 for Mass Effect. I don't understand why it was downvoted. Everything seems to be alright with it.

Comment: People can downvote for any reason they want.  I'm having trouble understanding how this isn't a duplicate of the first linked question.

Comment: @Frank, see my edit.

Comment: That makes it slightly clearer, yes.  Still pretty darn close, but not close for me to want to close it.

Answer (score 8):

By my reckoning, for straight male shep you have these options:

- Sha'ira
- Liara
- Ashley
- Kelly
- Miranda
- Tali
- Jack
- Gianna Parasini (I guess a [kiss on the cheek](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Gianna_Parasini) counts)
- Diana Allers
- Samara (??)

It seems to me that in order to have the maximum number of encounters, you have to carefully juggle the more "romantic" options while throwing in the more "casual" options whenever possible. Here's how I think it could work out.

**ME1**

- Express dissatisfaction with Sha'ira's gift.
- Romance both Ashley and Liara on the ship, pushing to the point where they confront you, and choose Ashley. Liara keeps a crush on you.

> If Shepard has been wooing Liara and the human love interest at the
>   same time (or if Shepard picked a bugged renegade option in not
>   showing interest in Liara), after the next completed mission on a
>   primary world, the Commander will suddenly be confronted by both
>   potential love interests after the debriefing. They will ask Shepard
>   to choose between them.

- Consummate with Ashley as soon as possible, but keep being as flirty as possible with Liara.

**ME2**

- It seems that Kelly can be had "on the side" of whatever else you do. (correct?)

> However, both male and female Shepard may also have romantic
>   interactions with the following characters [Kelly, Samara, Morinth], which do not prevent the
>   romancing of the main romance options but will not be rewarded with
>   the Paramour Achievement.

- You can have a quick fling with Jack early on.
- Because of a bug (maybe), you can romance Miranda and Tali and Jack after beating the game, [by sequentially breaking up with each and moving on to the next one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14964/is-it-possible-to-have-a-romance-with-all-your-possibilities-in-one-game).
- Help out Gianna and get yourself that kiss!
- Romance Samara as far as it will allow you to.
- Reaffirm your relationship with Liara in the Shadow Broker DLC, but then go right back to what you were doing with whoever on the ship.

**ME3**

- Take every opportunity with Diani Allers before locking in with anyone else.

> Sometimes Shepard can carefully time dialogs to bring about multiple
>   liaisons, particularly with non-squadmate characters such as Kelly
>   Chambers and Diana Allers

- Have Kelly on the side by meeting her on the Citadel and locking in with her first. The Romance Guide seems to support this:

> Kelly Chambers: After Priority: The Citadel II is over, speak to her
>   once after you complete each "main story" mission. Eventually,
>   slightly before you are required to begin Priority: Rannoch, Kelly
>   will question Shepard about a significant other; if Shepard replies
>   that Kelly is that person, they will share a quick romantic encounter
>   in the cabin. If you wish to two-time with Kelly and another romantic
>   interest, you must "lock in" with Kelly first.

- Kiss Samara in the Citadel DLC, but don't pursue any further (maybe even break up? Is this possible?)
- Eventually lock in with Liara to finally consummate with her.

It looks like the only person you can have multiple unique encounters with under this strategy is Kelly, since she is so casual and in two games. The others you'll have to settle for the once.

Answer (score -1):

Yes.
ME1: Liara
ME2: Jack as a fling, Miranda as Romance, flirt like crazy with Samara, LotSB lock in Liara.
ME3: Flirt with Liara and romance her when you speak to Miranda don't break up with her, you are now dating both Miranda and Liara. Make sure you do the Citadel Party after you save Miranda that way you get a date with Miranda, Kiss Samara, renegade on Omega, Lock in Liara.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Arqade. Your answer is slightly brief; could you elaborate on the exact steps required?